# Understanding create-react-app for creating redux typescript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, create-react-app

I forgot to use `redux-typescript` template while creating react app. That is, I created a react app with command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

instead of

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript
```

Now I have built a lot of UI and was to add redux layer. But now I realized that I should have created app with `redux-typescript` template. What should I do now? Will installing
`@reduxjs/toolkit` and `redux` have similar effect? That is will running below commands now will have same effect of creating app with `redux-typescript` template?

```
yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit
yarn add redux
```

Official doc [says](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#using-create-react-app):

> The recommended way to start new apps with React and Redux is by using the official Redux+JS template or Redux+TS template for Create React App, which takes advantage of Redux Toolkit and React Redux's integration with React components.

Does `redux-typescript` template of `create-react-app` does something more than installing installing `@reduxjs/toolkit` and `redux`?

Answer (score 1):

react-redux docs has lists two ways to for installation,

1. **Using `create-react-app`**

   npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript
2. **An Existing React App**

   yarn add react-redux

   You'll also need to install [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/installation) and [set up a Redux store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store/) in your app.

I guess later is what I was looking for. Unfortunately, neither [redux-core installation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/installation#redux-core) and [redux-toolkit installation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started#installation) web pages says it so clear.